# Change label text in a label array during runtime

Tags: java, runtime, label

I added an `array` of `labels` in a `panel`. How can I change the `label` display to some other text during runtime in `java`? for example(the label array reads `- - - - -`  then it has to change to `a p p l e` during runtime)

Comment: use String array, the assign it as jlabel array value while you adding them to jpanel

Answer (score 0):

Use label.setText("") method

Label label= new Label();
label.setText(text)